# python thread only prints to stdout after join

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I have a python program which I am trying to add a progress bar to.  My thread class is:

```
class ProgressThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ProgressThread, self).__init__()
        self.stoprequest = threading.Event()

    def run(self):
        while not self.stoprequest.is_set():
            print ".",
            time.sleep(5)

    def join(self, timeout=None):
        self.stoprequest.set()
        super(ProgressThread, self).join(timeout)
```

Then in my main thread I am using the thread class above like this:

```
progress_thread = ProgressThread()
progress_thread.start()
ret = long_running_method()
progress_thread.join()
```

The issue I am having is that the dots do not get printed until I call join().  The correct number of dots are there corresponding to the time it takes for long_running_method to complete but I want them to show up one by one just to show the user that the program is not hung.

Comment: Try adding `sys.stdout.flush()` after the `print`.

Comment: yes that is what the issue was...Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the issue is that when you use `print ".",` you're not printing out a newline character (the comma prevents that). By default, stdout is not flushed to the screen until it sees a newline `\n` character. You can get around this by adding `sys.stdout.flush()` after the `print` statement. That will force the output to be printed to screen.

Comment: why would output appear as expected in a CLI, but not appear when run via a process manager (circus in this case) until we add a call to flush()?

Answer (score 2):

Your code works fine for me in both Python 2.7.8 and 3.4.1 on mac. Here is my testcase:

```
import threading, time


class ProgressThread(threading.Thread):
   def __init__(self):
       super(ProgressThread, self).__init__()
       self.stoprequest = threading.Event()

   def run(self):
       while not self.stoprequest.is_set():
           print(".")
           time.sleep(1)

   def join(self, timeout=None):
       self.stoprequest.set()
       super(ProgressThread, self).join(timeout)

def long_running_method():
    time.sleep(5)

progress_thread = ProgressThread()
progress_thread.start()
ret = long_running_method()
progress_thread.join()
```

Could it be an output buffering issue with your terminal or operating system? Try flushing your output:

```
import sys
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: Your test case is missing the comma in the `print` statement, which makes all the difference.

Comment: @TheSoundDefense You're right. Adding the comma allows me to reproduce OP's problem, which is indeed a flushing issue.